# How can long lines be broken into multiple lines within Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

Some questions and answers on Stack Overflow include example code with long lines. The default display for this code seems to be to use a horizontal scroll bar. When trying to copy the code to run it, sometimes scrolling along the line is unwieldy. Any suggestions?

For example, if someone has a question about parsing a long string and they post an example like:

```
st1 = "Hello World 1 Hello World 2 Hello World 3 Hello World 4 Hello World 5 Hello World 6 Hello World 7 Hello World 8 Hello World 9 Hello World 10 Hello World 11 Hello World 12 Hello World 13 Hello World 14 Hello World 15 Hello World 16 Hello World 17 Hello World 18 Hello World 19 Hello World 20 Hello World 21 Hello World 22 Hello World 23 Hello World 24 Hello World 25 Hello World 26 Hello World 27 Hello World 28 Hello World 29 Hello World 30 Hello World 31 Hello World 32 Hello World 33 Hello World 34 Hello World 35 Hello World 36 Hello World 37 Hello World 38 Hello World 39 Hello World 40 Hello World 41 Hello World 42"
```

Is it possible to add a button to show this on multiple lines or easily grab the text? Of course it'd be preferable if the user already broke the code down using the relevant syntax for the specific language but that doesn't always happen.

Perhaps my issue is OS/Browser specific so I'll specify that I notice this with Firefox 41 and Safari 9 in Mac OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: If you double(triple?)-click on the line, is the whole line selected?

Comment: Yes, the triple click works perfectly.

Comment: Ok, had to read this twice. It's not a feature request for some sort of automated code line break [inserter-inator](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Doofenshmirtz's_schemes_and_inventions), but rather a feature request to make it easier to copy the code in a code block.

Comment: An automated code line break might be a nice option but approxiblue's solution makes it easy enough to copy to a text editor and examine there so it isn't necessary.

Comment: @approxiblue: Post it as an answer? Not everyone knows about such trick with their browser.